# Connect corners of two rectangles via SVG line in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, line, svg

Assuming I have two rectangles on a leaflet map with `CRS.Simple`, how can I use `svgOverlay` to draw a `<line>` that connect top left corner of the two rectangles? I'm having issue with spatial to screen coordinate conversions. Here's my code with two rectangles, one orange and one red. (see [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pine-zdnoz)):

```
const el = document.querySelector("#map");
const map = L.map(el, {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
var bounds = [
  [54.559322, -5.767822],
  [56.1210604, -3.02124]
];
// create an orange rectangle
L.rectangle(bounds, { color: "#ff7800", weight: 1 }).addTo(map);

var bounds2 = [
  [52.559322, -3.767822],
  [54.1210604, -3.02124]
];
L.rectangle(bounds2, { color: "red", weight: 1 }).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Idea is to do:

```js
var svgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgElement.setAttribute('xmlns', "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
svgElement.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 200 200");
svgElement.innerHTML = '<line stroke="black" x1="something" x2="something" y1="something" y2="something" />';
var svgElementBounds = [ [ 32, -130 ], [ 13, -100 ] ];
L.svgOverlay(svgElement, svgElementBounds).addTo(map);
```

What would be values for the `<line>`?

**First try**

```
const boundObj = L.latLngBounds(bounds)
const nw = map.latLngToContainerPoint(boundObj.getNorthWest()),
    x = nw.x,
    y = nw.y
```

**Second try**

```
const boundObj = L.latLngBounds(bounds)
const nw = map.latLngToLayerPoint(boundObj.getNorthWest()),
    x = nw.x,
    y = nw.y
```

Comment: To draw a line from point to point with s SVG overlay seems rather complicated and unefficient. Besides that, since SVG overlay is a vector layer, line width would change with zoom change. Any special reason for this and not using simple `L.polyline` for drawing a line?

Comment: @TomazicM okay, but then how do you find the latlngs of shortest distance between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, to draw a line from point to point with s SVG overlay would be rather complicated and unefficient. Besides that, since SVG overlay is a vector layer, line width would change with zoom change.

It's much simpler to simply draw a `L.polyline` line. When getting the righ coordinates for line start and end, the following has to be taken into account about `L.CRS.Simple` coordinate system:

- Origin is in the upper left corner, `x` goes down, `y` goes right.
- Order of coordinates in input parameters to Leaflet methods/function is `[y, x]`.

Taken that into account, code to draw a line from upper left corner of the first rectangle to upper left corner od the second rectangle could look msomething like this:

```
const map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
var bounds1 = [
  [54.559322, -5.767822],
  [56.1210604, -3.02124]
];
var upperLeft1 = [bounds1[1][0], bounds1[0][1]];
var rect1 = L.rectangle(bounds1, { color: "#ff7800", weight: 1 });

var bounds2 = [
  [52.559322, -3.767822],
  [54.1210604, -3.02124]
];
var upperLeft2 = [bounds2[1][0], bounds2[0][1]];
var rect2 = L.rectangle(bounds2, { color: "red", weight: 1 });

var line = L.polyline([upperLeft1, upperLeft2], {weight: 1});

var layerGroup = L.featureGroup([rect1, rect2, line]).addTo(map);
var layerGroupBounds = layerGroup.getBounds();

map.fitBounds(layerGroupBounds);
```

This would be the result:

[image]

Comment: Ha! I wonder why `[y, x]` and not `[x, y]`

Comment: You can read more about using `L.CRS.Simple` here: https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html. For order of coordinates, see section "This is not the LatLng you’re looking for".